# How do I scrape hyperlinks on a page using WatIn?

Tags: c#, filter, watin, bots, scrape

I'm trying to gather a list of hyperlinks (the url that it links to) using WatIn. I tried using:

```
            foreach (Link l in myIE.Links)
            {

                Links.Add(l.ToString());                    
            }


            string LinksCSV = string.Join(",", Links.ToArray());
            richTextBox2.Text = LinksCSV;
```

I am trying to list all hyperlinks in my richtextbox however the above returned the hyperlink name, so it showed "Link" over and over again.

Additionally I'm going to need to list only urls/links that contain "webpage.php?id=" and then has a unique number after that. How do I return the scraped urls filtered by only the ones that contain "webpage.php?id="?

UPDATE:
Here is an updated test that works using other sites, but not my required site. The below code works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using WatiN.Core;


namespace ScrapeTest
{
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IE ie = new IE();

        ie.GoTo("http://www.freesound.org/browse/tags/organ/");

        foreach (var currLink in ie.Links)
        {
            if (currLink.Url.Contains("sounds"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("contains Edit in the link Url" + currLink.Url);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

}
```

}

The code seems to be correct, however it's interaction with my specific url and hyperlinks seems to be the issue. The site and hyperlinks I'm after contain sensitive information, hence their omission.

Using my sites Main page http://website.com the script runs, so it is having an issue with regards to the unique page I send it to http://website.com/data.php?search=%22%22&cat=0
Could it be because of the .php in the url? 
Also the url's are stored on the page as shown below if it helps.

```
td class="alt2">
<a align="center" href="data.php?id=111111">EDIT</a>
/td>
```

UPDATE and SOLUTION: For some reason the issue seems to occur when I try to use the Url.Contains method. What I have ended up doing is storing every single scraped Url into a list and will test my list line by line as needed to return the required Urls. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code `myIE.Links` is a `LinkCollection`, meaning when you iterate through the `Link` objects you need to specify which property you want, in this case it will be `Url`

**Example** - Go to google.com and write out link addresses to the console.

```
    ie.GoTo("http://www.google.com");

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);   //<-- Added due to diagnose what might be a timing issue.

    foreach (var currLink in ie.Links)
    {
        if (currLink.Url.Contains("www.google.com"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("contains www.google.com in the link Url" + currLink.Url);
        }
    }
```

Tested on WatiN 2.1, IE9, Win7.

Comment: Your information seems like it should answer the question I had, however when I implement your solution I keep getting the error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. This occurs at the if statement. I don't understand why this error is being thrown?

Comment: Using your exact example works, however it does not work provided I use my own GoTo url, and my specific Url.Contains. When I substitute out google for my information to retrieve I get the NullReferenceException.

Comment: Without seeing your full code, I'm not going to be able to help besides making wild guesses which would include your your 'Links' object not being initialized correctly.

Update your question to include your full, complete, using www.google.com failing code and I'll take a look.

Comment: Given that the code works for one site and not another, could it be that your site is using an asynch call to build at least some of the page?  Perhaps add a Thread.Sleep() to make sure everything is finished.  Sleeping a thread is definitely a not-great way to wait for asynch calls to finish, but it is quick-n-easy to add for diagnosis.  See my updated code above.

Comment: Incorporating the Sleep code didn't resolve the error unfortunately. I added more details to the OP.

Comment: I'd take an adventure through the HTML of the problem page.  See anything out of the ordinary?  Malformed tags?  IFrames?   I've done basic automation on php pages without issue, so I doubt that is the issue.   My code above works without issue if pointed at http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [Contains()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/contains) as follows

```
foreach (Link l in myIE.Links)    
{  
            if(l.ToString().Contains("webpage.php?id="))
                Links.Add(l.ToString());  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however 2 issues arise. The first is that using the l.tostring() method returns the word "Link" not the hyperlink "webpage.php?.id=". The Second issue is that after I realized the first issue, I tested the code using Contains("Link") and it gives the error: NullReferenceException at the If statement.